# USB keyboard won't work with usbhid driver

Tags: debian, drivers, usb, keyboard

I have an HP thin client (model t5325) which runs Debian Linux (kernel 2.6.22.18-1-armel).  We are testing some kiosk keyboards from Operator Interface Technology which are presenting themselves to Linux as HID devices, but the OS will not bind the `usbhid` driver to the device and allow them to function properly.  Here is what the devices list show for the keyboard when connected:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 13 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=04d8 ProdID=ffd5 Rev= 1.73
S:  Manufacturer=Operator Interface Technology, Inc.
S:  Product=QVP01T
S:  SerialNumber=00003502
C:* #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   8 Ivl=10ms
I:* If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=(none)
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   3 Ivl=10ms
```

As you can see, the "Driver" for the two interfaces on the device shows "(none)" and isn't bound to anything.  I have tried to bind the device directly to the driver to no avail:

```
root@TC-40041:/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid# echo -n "1-1.1:1.0" > bind
-bash: echo: write error: No such device
```

I have also tried adding the vendor/product ID to the `new_id` file for the `usbhid` driver and get the same result:

```
root@TC-40041:/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid# echo 04d8 ffd5 > new_id
root@TC-40041:/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid# echo -n "1-1.1:1.0" > bind
-bash: echo: write error: No such device
```

The `1-1.1:1.0` comes from the USB device list:

```
root@TC-40041:/proc/bus/usb# ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov 30 12:08 1-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/ehci_marvell.70059/usb1/1-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov 30 12:08 1-1 -> ../../../devices/platform/ehci_marvell.70059/usb1/1-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov 30 14:10 1-1.1 -> ../../../devices/platform/ehci_marvell.70059/usb1/1-1/1-1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov 30 15:11 1-1.1:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/ehci_marvell.70059/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov 30 15:11 1-1.1:1.1 -> ../../../devices/platform/ehci_marvell.70059/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov 30 12:08 1-1:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/ehci_marvell.70059/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov 30 12:08 usb1 -> ../../../devices/platform/ehci_marvell.70059/usb1
```

The keyboard works okay when plugged into a Windows 7 PC (though it did go through a discovery process and install a device driver on its own).  The vendor claims the keyboards are designed as generic HID interfaces and should work on any modern operating system with USB support.  We have similar keyboards from another vendor which present themselves in much the same way to the operating system and they bind to the `usbhid` driver without error and work perfectly.  These do not.

Have we missed anything?  Are there other way we can attempt to bind the driver or have these keyboards work properly with Debian Linux?